# auto generate of category id doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I am a newbie in using aspnet , I have a problem regarding auto generate of id's can anyone tell if there's a problem regarding my code... the requirement is that whenever the user clicks add the   lbl_categorycode.Text should auto generate. THANKS IN ADVANCE:D

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Partial Class ADDCATEGORY
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CategoryTable (CategoryID, ProductCategory) VALUES ( '" & lbl_categorycode.Text & "' , '" & txt_productcategory.Text & "')"
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.Connection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Connection.Close()
        MsgBox("Record Added")
        Call gencategorycode()
        Call clear()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Call gencategorycode()
    End Sub
    Private Sub gencategorycode()
    Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand
    Dim rdr As SqlDataReader

    cmd1.Connection = cn
    cmd1.Connection.Open()
    cmd1.CommandText = "Select count(*) as s from CategoryTable "
    rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader

    If rdr.HasRows = True Then
        rdr.Read()
        lbl_categorycode.Text = Format(CInt(rdr(0).ToString) + 1, "ACECATN000000")

    Else
        lbl_categorycode.Text = "ACECATN0000001"
    End If
    cmd1.Connection.Close()
End Sub
Sub clear()
    txt_productcategory.Text = ""
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

you can't assume that the `rowCount+1` is going to be the next Id.let's say you have 4 records in database with ids 1,2,3,4. Then say you delete the record with id 2. Then you have count equal to 3.  So according to your algorithm the next record id will be 4. It is not goiing to work because there is a record with id 4 already in the database.

So what you can do is, let the database to generate the identity column. If you are using SQL Server  database   you can enable the Identity specification for a column. And you can get  last identity value inserted using a SQL command `SCOPE_IDENTITY`(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) .

Answer (score 0):

You want reproduce this ACECATN000000 into ACECATN000001 ?

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|example.MDF';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim selected As String = Left(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString, 1)
        Dim maximumfinaldata As String = ""
        cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(CategoryID) FROM CategoryTable WHERE (SUBSTRING(CategoryID,1,1)) ='" & Left(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString, 1) & "'", con)
        con.Open()
        Dim result As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While result.Read
            ''it will reproduce C002 AS A MAX VALUE because the maxdatavalue from mycode was 002
            Dim temp = result.GetValue(0)
            Dim number = CInt(Right(result.GetValue(0), 3))
            If number > 0 And number < 9 Then
                number += 1
                maximumfinaldata = "00" & CStr(number)
            ElseIf number > 9 And number < 99 Then
                number += 1
                maximumfinaldata = "0" & CStr(number)
            ElseIf number > 99 Then
                number += 1
                maximumfinaldata = CStr(number)
            End If
        End While
        MsgBox(maximumfinaldata)
        con.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Take a look

Comment: yes, i use count but is there other option to autogenerate the ID??

Comment: Count is to count your database row but not to get the MAX, I'd suggested you to use MAX to get the maximum data value

Comment: Check on my latest example, hope it could help you